# "NSS headers not found" error while building evolution-data-server-3.34.1 using cmake

Tags: compiling, evolution, cmake

I am installing Evolution Data Server from source using `cmake` by following command:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_OPENLDAP=OFF -DWITH_NSPR_INCLUDES=/usr/inclue/nspr/ ..
```

But it result in following error message:

```
-- Looking for 3 include files nss.h, ..., smime.h
-- Looking for 3 include files nss.h, ..., smime.h - not found
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindSMIME.cmake:124 (message):
  NSS headers not found.  Use -DWITH_NSS_INCLUDES=/path/to/nss to specify the include dir of NSS.
```

Any one could help me to solve this problem?

**NOTE1:** `-DWITH_OPENLDAP=OFF` is added because `cmake` gives me an error if I do not use this phrase.

**NOTE2:** thanks to @"Knud Larsen" comment `-DWITH_NSPR_INCLUDES=/usr/inclue/nspr/` is added to solve similar problem about nspr include files. but I can not find similar path to solve the problem for NSS include files/

Comment: NSPR headers not found :  `sudo apt install libnspr4-dev` ... https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libnspr4-dev/filelist ... Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libnspr&searchon=names

Comment: Are you following the instructions in the [README.md](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/) file? it seems that there are some quite complex dependencies. See also [Building Evolution from sources](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/Building) (although it appears to be RPM focused - you will need to translate the packages to their Debian/Ubuntu equivalents)